# web API in Azure: Authorization has been denied for this request

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a SQL Azure database up and running. The connection string I'm using for one web api application.

When I'm running the application through Visual Studio using SQL Azure connection string, I'm not getting any Authorization denied response.

Now I deployed my web api application to Azure and when I'm trying to access any API controller, it's saying `Authorization has been denied for this request.`

I also checked Authentication / Authorization settings for my App Service and it's.... Anonymous access is enabled on the App Service app. Users will not be prompted for login.

[image]

Why I'm getting  Authorization denied response. Is there any settings I'm missing?

Comment: Is that a `401 Unauthorized HTTP` response? Did you decorate your controllers with `[Authorize]` by any chance? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api#using-the-authorize-attribute). That doesn't really explain why it's all good when running locally but then again i'm not that great with Web API 2, so maybe your project is overriding that when local/DEBUG.

Comment: No. I don't decorate with 'Autorized'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like one/more of your Controllers in your API code have the '[Autorized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx#Examples)' attribute set. Remove it, and it should work.

Comment: No. I don't decorate with  'Autorized'

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Could you add a screenshot of the "Authentication/Authorization" blade for your api app from the Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0):

Did api call request reached the controller?
Did you tried to debug the azure api from cloud explorer from VS? Just debug and see if your request hitting the controller action.